# Convert a large grayscale PIL image to black and transparent

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use a large 2d array to create an image mask with black and transparent parts. Originally, the input 2d array was a `PIL.Image` that was loaded in grayscale (`'L'`) mode. So it contains values between 0 and 255. And now I want to replace all the 0s with `[0,0,0,255]` (black stays black) and all values >0 should be `[0,0,0,0]` (transparent). I can do this simply like this:

```
import numpy as np

# generate some random test data - normally I just read the input image, which is fast
input_data = np.array([np.array([random.choice([0,10]) for x in range(22000)]) for y in range(9000)])

# create a new img containing black and transparent pixels (r,g,b,alpha) and this takes ages
overlay_img = [[[0, 0, 0, 255] if input_data[y][x] == 0 else [0, 0, 0, 0] for x in range(len(input_data[0]))] for y in range(len(input_data))]
overlay_img = np.array(overlay_img)
```

This takes quite some time because the input data is so large (~22000x9000). I am curious if it is somehow possible to do this faster. I also tried `np.where`, but I could not get it to work. Maybe there is even a way to directly change the PIL image?

fyi: In the end, I just want to plot this image on top of my matplotlib plot with `imshow`, so that only the relevant regions are visible (where the image is transparent) and the rest is hidden/black.

Here just a very quick and small example of what I want to do:
[image]

Comment: I fail to see why you need a 4-channel image when the first 3 channels are all zero anyway. Nor do I understand why you are making Numpy arrays but using list comprehensions. Please show how you plan to use this *"mask"* and what effect you want it to create. Thank you.

Comment: To your second question: True, I do not need numpy arrays. I just used them in the example, because in my case the input was a 2d numpy array, and I had previously tried `numpy.where`. But if it also works without numpy arrays, then great! As to your first question: that is why I wrote the last paragraph: I want to use imshow with this black and transparent image so that the layers below are either hidden or shown in the final figure. Can I visualize a black and transparent image with only one channel?

Comment: It seems we are mis-communicating! I was suggesting you do not use list comprehensions and that you DO use Numpy arrays because they are faster. I also wanted to see the code you want to use to display the image please and how it is supposed to look. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this, but you haven't shown your code for `imshow()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random
import numpy as np

# Set up dimensions and random input image
h, w = 9000, 22000
im = np.random.randint(0, 11, (h,w), dtype=np.uint8)

# Create 4-channel mask image
mask = np.zeros((h,w,4), dtype=np.uint8)
mask[...,3] = (im==0) * 255
```

The last line takes 800ms on my MacBook Pro.

---

If you need a bit more performance, you can use `numexpr` as follows and the time required is 300ms instead of 800ms:

```
import random
import numexpr as ne
import numpy as np

# Set up dimensions and random input image
h, w = 9000, 22000
im = np.random.randint(0, 11, (h,w), dtype=np.uint8)

# Create 4-channel mask image
mask = np.zeros((h,w,4), dtype=np.uint8)

# Same but with "numexpr"
mask[...,3] = ne.evaluate("(im==0)*255")
```

Comment: Thank you! This is sooo much faster than my list comprehension. I suspected that there might be a quick numpy solution. And `mask[...,3] = (im==0) * 255` is really neat.